# Group price for product

Tags: magento2, price, group, group-price

I have create 4 group of customer and try to set group price for each group in product but i dont see any group price section in product and I want to add customer group wise price for particular product how can i do in magento version 2.0.7 ?

Answer (score 1):

There has been changed the use of group prices in Magento 2 and higher. They are integrated with tier prices and now you can set tier price per customer group (see the screenshot)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2NAh.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tier price with the quantity = 1 as group price.